# JSONGenerator error

Tags: apex, json

Hi I need to create a json object iteratively inside a for loop on a keyset of a map: Below my code:

```
List<String> ts= new List<String>(); 
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
        Set<String> k=mapTypeSubType.keySet();
         gen.writeStartObject();
        for(String key:k){
            if(key !='' && key !=null ){
                System.debug(i);
                i++;
                System.debug('key ' +key);
                System.debug(mapTypeSubType.get(key));
                gen.writeStringField('type',key);
                gen.writeObjectField('subtypes', mapTypeSubType.get(key));
                gen.writeEndObject();
                String pretty = gen.getAsString();
                ts.add(pretty);
            }    
        }
```

the for loop  did one cycle and throw the error "Can not write a field name, expecting a value". How can I do a List of String while I build iteratively a JSON?

Comment: Can't you use [JSON.serialize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_json.htm) method instead of the createGenerator parser. Otherwise, can you post a snippet of code which is not working.

Comment: I post the code that is not working. I can't use JSON serialize because I sent the result to a method that want a specific data structure

Comment: I can't run the code, post a working copy of it. You would get better support if you do that

Comment: You're doing `writeEndObject()` inside your loop. Seems like `writeStartObject()` should either be moved into the loop, or `writeEndObject()` should move out of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your requirement is to create JSON list you should create the JSON string inside the for loop itself. I tried to modify your code as below. Please check if this is working for you.

```
List<String> ts= new List<String>();
Set<String> k=mapTypeSubType.keySet();
JSONGenerator gen;
String pretty;
for(String key:k){    
    if(key !='' && key !=null ){
        gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
        gen.writeStartObject();        
        gen.writeStringField('type',key);
        gen.writeObjectField('subtypes', mapTypeSubType.get(key));
        gen.writeEndObject();
        pretty = gen.getAsString();
        ts.add(pretty);        
    }
}
System.debug('%%% '+ts);
```